# How to select an element based on the value of a nested sibling in XPath?

Tags: xpath

In a document containing a large number of DIVs, I want to select the text inside the `asset-body` elements, but only if the `bookmark` link inside the `asset-name entry-title` of that "entry" contains the text `democrat` in the `href` value.

So, in the example below, containing two "entries" (`entry-1` and `entry-2`), I only want the text that says **`Jackpot!`** because the value of the `bookmark` link in that "entry" contains the substring `democrat`:

```
http://blahblah.com/politics-democrat
```

Is it possible to do this using XPath?

ENTRY 1: (**FAIL**: `bookmark` link in that entry **lacks the substring `democrat`**)

```
<div id="entry-1" class="item-asset asset hentry">
  <div class="asset-header">
    <h2 class="asset-name entry-title">
      <a rel="bookmark" href="http://blahblah.com/paper-scissors">Paper Scissors</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="asset-content entry-content">
    <div class="asset-body">
     <p>Paper and scissors</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ENTRY 2: (**PASS**: `bookmark` link in that entry **contains the substring `democrat`**)

```
<div id="entry-2" class="item-asset asset hentry">
  <div class="asset-header">
    <h2 class="asset-name entry-title">
      <a rel="bookmark" href="http://blahblah.com/politics-democrat">Pelosi Q&amp;A</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="asset-content entry-content">
    <div class="asset-body">
     <p>Jackpot!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted text nodes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//div[contains(
            div/h2[
              contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' asset-name ')
              and
              contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' entry-title ')
            ]/a[@rel='bookmark']/@href
         ,'democrat')
        ]/div/div[
           contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' asset-body ')
           ]//text()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more verbose than Dimitre's answer but it also includes more requirements regarding dom structure, which could be a good thing. Have to do some testing now.

Comment: @Alejandro: Dimitre's class test is much simpler of course: `@class='asset-body'`. Its simplicity also makes it easier to read. Perhaps it's necessary though? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//div[@class='item-asset asset hentry' 
    and .//a[contains(@href, 'democrat')]
     ]
     /following-sibling::div[@class='asset-body']/p/text()
```

Comment: Very concise. Thanks. What's the purpose of the dot here: `.//a` ? Does that mean the anchor has to be within a `//div[@class='item-asset asset hentry'`?

Comment: @August: `.//a` is equivalent to `descendant-or self::a` it means: select all `a` elements that are either descendents of the context node or the context node itself, if it is an `a` element. @Mads-Hansen in his answers follows more strictly the XML structure shown by you, while I give a more general expression that will select the wanted nodes even if your example wasn't exactly representing the exact xml structure.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Also, I notice you say `@class='asset-body'` whereas Alejandro says `contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' asset-body ')`. Is this just a style difference?

Comment: @August Padding the `@class` with spaces ensures that testing `contains()` with a space padded value will match whether the value was the first, last, or middle NMTOKEN.

Comment: @August: @Mads-Hansen assumes that `'asset-body'` is not the exact class, but that the class *contains*  `'asset-body'` and may also contain other text.

Answer (score 1):

> In a document containing a large
>   number of DIVs, I want to select the
>   text inside the `asset-body` elements,
>   but only if the `bookmark` link inside
>   the `asset-name entry-title` of that
>   "entry" contains the text `democrat` in
>   the `href` value.

```
//*[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),
                    ' hentry ')]
   [.//*[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),
                         ' asset-name ')]
        [contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),
                         ' entry-title ')]
        //a[@rel='bookmark']
           [contains(@href,'democrat')]]
   //*[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),
                       ' asset-body ')]
```

Comment: Cool. What's the `//*` for? Does that mean "any element" - not just DIVs?

Comment: @August: Yes. I'm supposing a very relax schema because your use of microformats.

Comment: @August HTML `@class` can contain any number of NMTOKENS (space separated values). It is a more "safe" match for those values that will avoid a false-positive partial word match.

Comment: @August: I have nothing to add to @Mads Hansen excellent comment. About hAtom microformat check http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom