# Importance of comparing the attribute using contains() and concat() function instead of directly comparing using = operator

Tags: xpath

To compare the attribute value

```
<div class="asset-body">
```

should the functions contains() and concat() has to be used like

```
contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' asset-body ')
```

as mentioned in the post's [How to select an element based on the value of a nested sibling in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066062/how-to-select-an-element-based-on-the-value-of-a-nested-sibling-in-xpath) accepted answer.

or merely using

```
@class='asset-body'
```

is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you know there is only a single `class` value used in your input element's attribute then certainly `@class = 'asset-body'` suffices. However (X)HTML in general allows the `class` attribute value to be a space separated list of class names and these days with the wide spread use of CSS it is not unusual to have various class names used, so to cater for that case doing `contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' asset-body ')` is necessary. Thus if you control the input and know for sure only one class value is used on the input elements you check with XPath then use the short expression, otherwise use the long one.